# What is wrong with using a bare 'except'?

Tags: python, except

I tried making a function to check if an image is displayed on the screen using PyAutoGui and came up with this:

```
def check_image_on_screen(image):
    try:
        pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

And it works fine, but PyCharm tells me I shouldn't leave `except` bare. What is the problem with leaving it like this? Is there a more appropriate way of creating the same function?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990718/20670

Comment: Wikipedia has some good information on this--it's called [error hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of that. This is asking "Why not bare except" while that one is asking "How do I bare except." A _good_ answer for the latter probably answers the former, but that doth not a duplicate make.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Bare `except` will catch exceptions you almost certainly don't want to catch, including `KeyboardInterrupt` (the user hitting Ctrl+C) and Python-raised errors like `SystemExit`

If you don't have a specific exception you're expecting, at least `except Exception`, which is the base type for all "Regular" exceptions.

---

That being said: you use `except` blocks to recover from known failure states. An unknown failure state is usually irrecoverable, and it is *proper behavior* to fatally exit in those states, which is what the Python interpreter does naturally with an uncaught exception.

Catch everything you know how to handle, and let the rest propagate up the call stack to see if something else can handle it. In this case the error you're expecting (per [the docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) is `pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException`

Comment: One example where you may want to catch every exception is when using databases. Catch all and do some cleanup.

Comment: I believe multiprocessing is another example, to avoid stuck sub-processes adequately terminating the pool.

Comment: You should consider context managers for both of these cases.

Comment: Those are both examples where you might want to use `try/finally` rather than `try/except`. Using finally means that you can guarantee cleanup but the exception will still be propagated afterwards.

Comment: Another example is when a process is not important. For example, sending a notification. I don't want the flow of everything to stop if I fail to send a notification, so I catch it, log it, and continue

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali don't you, though? If you get an exception that indicates an ephemeral network error, wouldn't you want to log and retry your notification rather than log and continue?

Comment: @AdamSmith indeed, we do retry the notification, but if it just keeps failing. I don't want that to stop everything. We realized that in the Great Slack Failure of 2021, where deployments were failing simply because they couldn't send a Slack notification

Comment: What this answer doesn't explain is why `except Exception:` raises a similar warning until you add a bare `raise` at the end of the block.  Yet `except:`...`raise` still gives you the warning.  In that context you almost certainly **do** want to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt`.  Exception blocks ending in a bare raise are virtually always (a)logging and (b) cleaning up / rolling back.  I wonder if there are other similar exceptions which are somehow dangerous to catch even with a bare raise at the end.

Comment: Incidentally you only use a context manager where one has been implemented by the library.  Plenty don't.  And context managers don't commonly distinguish between success and failure. I've hit plenty of scenarios where I needed cleanup which *must not* be executed on success (unlike a SQL ROLLBACK).

Comment: How can I find out what the exact exception name is? So as I can copy and paste it

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 The exception should be visible in the stack trace. For example try doing `[][0]` and observe the stack says "IndexError," or `{"ok":None}['nope']` and observe the stack says "KeyError"

Answer (score 38):

Basically, you're not taking advantage of the language to help you find problems.  If you used `except Exception as ex:` you could do something like log the exception and know exactly what happened.

Comment: No. The whole point here is why it's bad to use a bare except.

Comment: I mean to say: Logging is one of the **good** times to use a bare except, as called out in [PEP-8 under "Programming Recommendations"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): _A good rule of thumb is to limit use of bare ‘except’ clauses to two cases: 1. If the exception handler will be printing out or logging the traceback; at least the user will be aware that an error has occurred. ..._ Logging is not a good example of why it's bad to use a bare except.

Comment: Yeah, that's plausible, and certainly okay for class assignments and the like. But in production-quality code, it means you're concealing the issue _from the code_ at run time, and that's unwise.

I can't even begin to count how many times I saw a fault that was either ignored completely because, hey, we can just log it, or turned into a program that failed by a generic exception propagated to the top level.

Comment: No, I'm telling you why you don'twant bare excepts in production code. I've been doing this for over 50 years.

Comment: With a subsiquent bare `raise`, there's no code path that would allow this to conceal the issue from code. And python is not a 50 year old language. And I've been managing production code quite a while too. My comments are not about experience but logical possibility in the language.

Answer (score 0):

Removing bare `except:` is sometimes a good idea but not always.  Beware about Pycharm's warming on this.

PyCharm is reporting a warning from pycodestyle which cannot enforce the rule correctly so it enforces the rule incorrectly.  *See issue: [E722: (bare excepts) too strict (reraise)](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/703)*

As a general rule:

- bare except for **cleanup** is the nearly always the right thing to do when `finally:` won't do.
- bare except for **logging** often the right thing to do, but depends on whether you want to see logging of deliberate exit.

In both cases you MUST re-raise with a subsiquent bare `raise`.

#### PEP 8 Says:

> A bare except: clause will catch `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions that signal program errors, use `except Exception:` (bare except is equivalent to `except BaseException:`).
> A good rule of thumb is to limit use of bare ‘except’ clauses to two cases:
>
> 1. If the exception handler will be printing out or logging the traceback; at least the user will be aware that an error has occurred.
> 2. If the code needs to do some cleanup work, but then lets the exception propagate upwards with raise. try...finally can be a better way to handle this case.

### General Advice

#### Always Re-raise a bare except

##### Good:

```py
try:
    do_something()
except:
    logging.exception("Failed")
    raise
```

##### Bad

```py
try:
    do_something()
except:
    logger.exception("Failed")
```

This just ate a Ctrl-C or SystemExit

#### Make sure you always clean up

In cases were you need to clean up on error (and only on error), bare except is better

##### Good

```py
file = open("my_file.txt", "w")
try:
    with file:
        file.write("something")
except:
    os.unlink("my_file.txt")
    raise
```

##### Bad

```py
file = open("my_file.txt", "w")
try:
    with file:
        file.write("something")
except Exception:
    os.unlink("my_file.txt")
    raise
```

If the user hits CTRL-C at the keyboard at the wrong moment, the file get's left behind.